# Travis CLI: Encrypting with "travis encrypt" returns — resource not found ({"file":"not found"})

Tags: travis-ci, travis-ci-cli

I am trying to encrypt token in **.travis.yml** file using command `travis encrypt 123 --add deploy.api_key --pro` regarding Travis CI [docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/heroku).

Instead I got in console `resource not found ({"file":"not found"})`

**Prerequisites**:

I have installed Travis CLI on my machine. Also I successfully logged in travis from CLI with command `travis login --github-token {tokenHere} --com`. Github is connected with Travis CI.

**Result** with --debug —
[command result with --debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8RG4.png)

If I go manually to [https://api.travis-ci.com/repos/{Nickname}/HerokuTest](https://api.travis-ci.com/repos/%7BNickname%7D/HerokuTest) I receive an XML file with info about the project.

Please, can you tell me, how can I see what is wrong here, or where else I can seek?

Comment: I am having same problem

Comment: @jpell Actually, I haven't found a solution, I just tried same command "travis encrypt 123 --add deploy.api_key --pro" and it is working now for some reason.

There was new string in CLI: 
Detected repository as Nickname/repo, is this correct? |yes| yes

Answer (score 1):

Resource not found basically means that Travis isn't able to find your project. As far as I know, secrets are associated with the project, so Travis needs to find which project are you generating your secrets for. All that said, you're probably missing the -r flag. Try something like this:

```
travis encrypt aws_secret_access_key=very_secret_string -r mygithubusername/reponame --com
```

Comment: It is working now without -r flag, I don't have any ideas what was wrong, and why is it working now. Just used same command.

Comment: Adding this -r and myPrivateRepo worked for me as well